# Word for something that if you take it away it ceases to mean that thing

Tags: terminology

For the life of me I cannot think of the term that refers to an aspect of something, that if taken away, ceases to be that thing. A debatable and flawed example would be the idea that without my brain/consciousness I cease to be me because in effect, my brain/consciousness is what makes me me and is my very essence. Whereas, I would still be me if I lost an arm or something. So essentially, its something, that without, ceases to be the same thing.

Comment: Sine qua non. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_qua_non "is an indispensable and essential action, condition, or ingredient. It was originally a Latin legal term for "[a condition] without which it could not be", or "but for..." or "without which [there is] nothing"."

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Please be aware that questions are subject to editing and closure, and that reflects the site's policies on acceptable questions and NOT a personal attack. [What to avoid in questions](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions, including those that are closed, can be edited to bring them within guidelines. [Keeping questions on-topic](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Additional clarification at [the meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Essential definitions are often defined in terms of sufficiency and necessity. But I like sine qua non better.

Answer (score 5):

You mean an *essential property*. See [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/essential-accidental/): "an *essential property* of an object is a property that it must have".

Comment: This is rather brief for an answer; it is more like a comment. But I agree that what the OP appears to have in mind is an essential property. If an essential property is removed, something ceases to be the kind of thing it is. Thus the essence of a (geometrical) square is that it is a plane figure with four equal sides and with every angle a right angle. These are essential properties; if I remove one side, then the figure ceases to be a square.

Comment: There's indeed a tendency in Philosophy SE to give answers as comments :)

Comment: Do you think an example, along the lines of your comment, would improve the answer?

Comment: This was the exact answer I was thinking of, but, I was struggling between "comment and it's an answer", and, "it's philosophy, yes, but is this an english s.e. question?"  (And I'm still struggling with that...)

Comment: Well, it's a question on a term of art in philosophy. I think that should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

Richard Swinburne, in his [Mind, Brain, and Free Will](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R18J8OJA7QPLKX/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0199662576), distinguished between objects which do not have an essence, but are instead just temporary collections, and objects which do have an essence.  The term he used was "thisness". This term is translated from the Latin "haeccity".

Here are a few more references:  https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/thematic/haecceity-and-thisness/v-1 https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/medieval-haecceity/ https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?cc=mqr;c=mqr;c=mqrarchive;idno=act2080.0057.105;g=mqrg;rgn=main;view=text;xc=1